# How to properly call asyncronous service witin syncronous method

Tags: java, asynchronous, design-patterns, service

I am client, that uses service.

I call method of service, that works asynchronously. Thats mean that method immediately returns some identifier(id), and then i should periodically check by this id, is task finished or not. For example, service provide three methods:

```
service.startTask(someData) //starts task and returns its id
service.isTaskFinished(taskId) // checks is task finished
service.getTaskResult(taskId) //returns task results
```

I need to realize method in java, that starts task, waits when task finished and then returns result of task. Only solution that i can imagine is about:

```
...
public Object invokeAsyncTaskAndGetResults(int someData) {

    int taskId = service.startTask(someData);

    int sleepTime = 1000;
    int maxCheckCount = 5;
    boolean hasResults = false;

    int i = 1;
    while (i <= maxCheckCount && !hasResults) {
        hasResults = service.isTaskFinished(taskId );
        i++;
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
    }

    if (!hasResults)
        throw new NotResultEcxeption(); //for exapmle, throw exception if task was not finished 

    Object result = service.getTaskResult(taskId);
    return result;
}
...
```

I want to ask you advice: is this pattern solution ok? Is using Thread.sleep() a good practice to periodically check task results? Or may be you can advice some frameworks for better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As often, the answer is: it depends.

It really depends on the exact nature of that *service* you are using. If that thing only has interface to push a job; and later query by id; then your code is "pretty much" what can be done. In that sense, **pulling** is the only option then. You could further separate concerns/responsibilities in your code (for example by having thread A just poll forever to only stop when a result becomes available; and another thread B that checks if A still exists at some defined point in the future, to then kill it).

The alternative would be if your *service* also has means to **push** your code; in other words *invoke* a *callback* method; then things are different.

Answer (score 1):

The asynchronous task should have some kind of list of `listeners` for some events that can happen. If so then you should `wait` on some locking object in the asynchronous call and `notify` that lock when the `listener` is invoked.
Otherwise you have to use `pulling` design (with `Thread.sleep`).